# Save checkboxlist values to xml using vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, checkboxlist

I have some checkboxlist like this:

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="G1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Comunicações Unificadas" Text="Comunicações Unificadas - UCoIP"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Gestão Documental" Text="Gestão Documental - iPortalDoc"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Gestão Conteúdos Web" Text="Gestão de Conteúdos Web"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Promoção Websites" Text="Promoção de Websites"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Serviços de Consultoria" Text="Serviços de Consultoria"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

When submitting the form than contains them, i want to save all the selected values in a xml file.

At the moment if i select more than one value to submit, in the xml file i only get the first selected, the others do not appear in the file.

I'm saving the values in the xml file this way:

Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load(LocalizacaoFicheiro)

```
    Dim visitor As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Cliente")

    Dim res1 As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Resposta1")
    res1.InnerText = G1.SelectedValue.ToString


    visitor.AppendChild(res1)

    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(visitor)

    doc.Save(LocalizacaoFicheiro)
```

I need to change something in the way that i save the data to xml, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CheckBoxList.SelectedValue` is just a single value, so of course you're only getting one value when you use that property. [From its definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) it's designed to give you only the first selected value:

> If multiple items are selected, the value of the selected item with the lowest index is returned.

Use `CheckBoxList.Items` instead, looping through all of them and checking the `ListItem.Selected` property to see if they've been selected or not. (Or use the equivalent LINQ expression, whichever you prefer.)